# Как сделать аутентификацию юзера вручную?

Tags: php, laravel, интернет-магазин

Мне нужно написать интернет-магазин с подпиской через laravel, но стандартная форма аутентификации мне не подходит потому что она слишком мала и не поддерживает регистрацию через соцсети. Какой алгоритм создания аутентификации в Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала что вам конкретно нужно, написать самому или просто использовать уже имеющиеся на просторах git пакеты ?

Если самому то все в ваших руках, создаём недостающие таблицы и поля в уже имеющийся таблице `users` из коробки, смотрим документацию интересующей нас соц сети и пишем. При чем все соц сети уже работают по принципу OAuth [Читать тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) и [тут](https://oauth.net/2/).

Если вас интересует готовое решение то тут выбор чрезвычайно велик. Могу выделить самые популярные пакеты: [Eloquent OAuth](https://github.com/adamwathan/eloquent-oauth-l5) и [Laravel Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) + Можно много найти на свой вкус [тут](https://packagist.org/search/?q=laravel%205%20social).

P.s. Не зная что за версия Laravel допускаю что 5+

Comment: С версии 5.2 аутификацию можно установить "с коробки" через командную строку

Comment: @MaxSuprunenko доки пожалуйста